# Sort List with Linq, with groups alphabetic

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a class Guest

```
class Guest
{
   bool f = true;
   bool g = false;
   bool s = false;
   string name = "";
}
```

And a List where all the included -> `var g = new List<Guest>();`
It can be only one of the booleans true.

At the start come all the f guest then g guest in the middle and at last the s guest.
But all guest must be sorted alphabetic in f or g or in the a group.

Maybe so?

```
 var query = (from Guest in GuestList
                             orderby Guest.f, Guest.g, Guest.s, Guest.name
                             select Guest);
```

I'm just not it.

Thanks and greetz, Malte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.  The Sort and OrderBy will use the CopmpareTo() method

```
    public class Guest : IComparable<Guest>
    {
        public bool f { get; set; }
        public bool g { get; set; }
        public bool s { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Guest other)
        {
            int results = 0;

            if (this.f)
            {
                if (other.f)
                {
                    results = this.name.CompareTo(other.name);
                }
                else
                {
                    results = 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (other.f)
                {
                    results = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (this.g)
                    {
                        if (other.g)
                        {
                            results = this.name.CompareTo(other.name);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            results = 1;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (other.g)
                        {
                            results = -1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (this.s)
                            {
                                if (other.s)
                                {
                                    results = this.name.CompareTo(other.name);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    results = 1;
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                results = this.name.CompareTo(other.name);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
```

Below is simpler method which will even work with when more than one property is true.  Notice that I used 1,2,4 instead of 1,2,3 as in other solutions.  1,2,3 has issue that there is more than one way of getting 3 when multiple properties are true.

```
   public class Guest : IComparable<Guest>
    {
        public bool f { get; set; }
        public bool g { get; set; }
        public bool s { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Guest other)
        {
            int results = 0;
            int thisRank = (this.f ? 1 : 0) + (this.g ? 2 : 0) + (this.s ? 4 : 0);
            int otherRank = (other.f ? 1 : 0) + (other.g ? 2 : 0) + (other.s ? 4 : 0);

            if (thisRank == otherRank)
            {
                results = this.name.CompareTo(other.name);
            }
            else
            {
                results = thisRank.CompareTo(otherRank);
            }

            return results;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I couldn't sleep last night.  Got up and realized I was missing a few -1.  Just got up this morning and fixed the original code and added simpler method. which assigns 1,2,4 to the properties.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like pretty typical nested sorting.  There is no need to group.

```
var result = source
  .OrderBy(guest =>
    guest.f ? 1 :
    guest.g ? 2 :
    guest.s ? 3 :
    4)
  .ThenBy(guest => guest.name);
```

---

For those who are unfamiliar with the syntax, allow me to read the code.

- In the call to `OrderBy`, there is a lambda function which uses a chained ternary operator to generate a sort key for each row.  `OrderBy` sorts by this sort key.
- The result of `OrderBy` is an `IOrderedEnumerable<Guest>` and is passed to `ThenBy`.
- `ThenBy` preserves the sorting of the prior ordering operations and works to break ties.

Answer (score -1):

here is David B's example with more common syntax for the if statements.

```
var result = source
            .OrderBy(guest => { if (guest.f == true) return 1 else
                                if (guest.g == true) return 2 else
                                if (guest.s == true) return 3 else return 4;})
            .ThenBy(guest => guest.name);
```